# split 1 column in 5 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a relatively simple problem (I think), but I can not get my head around it. I have a single column with 200 records. The values of the rows are a list of numbers 1-200 (No duplicates). I would like to organize the numbers in 5 columns with the data sorted horizontally (Ascending A-Z). Example:

```
Original table:
Column1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
...and so on to 200
```

The view result should look like this:

```
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|
   1    2    3    4    5
   6    7    8    9   10
   11   12  ...an so on to 200
```

I looked into PIVOTING but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Use pivot and add when-case based on condition like value%5 and map to corresponding target columns.

Comment: No  dublicates, no gaps, 1..200. It sounds like a constant table, why derive it from the other table?

Comment: The number will change as new record are added over the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try a pivot query where the group is defined as the column minus one, divided by 5.  This places the first five records into the first group/row, the next five into the second group/row, and so on.  Then, we pivot on each `Column1 % 5` value to determine into which of the five columns each value will go.

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Column1 % 5 = 1 THEN Column1 END) AS Col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Column1 % 5 = 2 THEN Column1 END) AS Col2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Column1 % 5 = 3 THEN Column1 END) AS Col3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Column1 % 5 = 4 THEN Column1 END) AS Col4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Column1 % 5 = 0 THEN Column1 END) AS Col5
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    (Column1 - 1) / 5;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: This works great. Thank you much for giving me a working example. A+